# Flutter achieve Cupertino-like scaled-down background of bottom sheet with go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to achieve a Cupertino-like dropback effect as shown in this demo [here](https://jamesblasco.github.io/modal_bottom_sheet/#/) (see Cupertino Modal fit example) using the modal_bottom_sheet package.

In their demo, they make use of the `MaterialWithModalsPageRoute` class in the `onGenerateRoute`, which allows to cancel the transition animation if the pushed route is a full screen dialog. However, I'm using go_router, which does not necessarily know about the `Route` API according to my research, therefore I cannot directly use the `MaterialWithModalsPageRoute` in the `onGenerateRoute`.

Now, the question is how this effect could be achieved using go_router. I have some `CupertinoModalBottomSheetRoute`s from the modal_bottom_sheet package, which I integrated in the following way through the `pageBuilder` property of `GoRoute`:

```dart
class CupertinoModalBottomSheetPage<T> extends Page<T> {
  final Widget child;

  const CupertinoModalBottomSheetPage({
    required this.child,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Route<T> createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoModalBottomSheetRoute(
      expanded: true,
      settings: this,
      builder: (context) => child,
    );
  }
}
```

This works as expected, however, it's missing the typical "dropback" effect from native Cupertino apps.

Has anyone had a similar issue or any ideas how this could be achieved using go_router?

Thanks in advance!